# XMonad: workspaces seem not to be working

Tags: xmonad, xmobar

I have a problem. When I press Mod4+[1..9] the workspace does not work...

And when I use `wmctrl`:

```
wmctrl -m
```

My output is:

> Cannot get window manager info properties.
> (_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK or _WIN_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK)